# Hide menu after click

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript nav menu that drops down. Currently, it only closes if you press the X or click outside the menu. I'd like for it to close after a user clicks on a link inside the menu as well.

Here's the html:

```
<nav>
    <div class="main-nav navbtn">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx dropbtn">
        <span>toggle menu</span>
      </button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home" class="home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
        <a href="#work">Work</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And here's the javascript.

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
     }
    }
   };
```

What do I need to do to make this functionality happen? Thanks!

Edit: Here's the code for the scroll function if it helps.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:not(.external)', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});

var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function () {
  $root.animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList, not an Array.  You just need to change . . .

```
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
```

to . . .

```
var dropdowns = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content"));
```

You can also makes thing a little more concise using . . .

```
dropdowns.forEach(function (openDropdown) {
    dropdown.classList.contains('show') && dropdown.classList.remove('show');
});
```

Comment: A NodeList is still an *array-like* object, having a `length` property and indexes. It should behave the same as an Array when using a `for` loop and counter.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You're correct.  I guess I'm too used to using `forEach` instead of `for` loops.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I changed the code, but it's still not closing after a menu click. If it helps, here's the code for the scroll scripts.

Comment: $(document).on('click', 'a:not(.external)', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});

var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function () {
  $root.animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
  return false;
});